# Why Laravel does not optimize model queries automatically?

Tags: mysql, laravel, doctrine, query-builder, rdbms

Till today I was relying on Laravel relationships, but since I opened mysql logs I was very disappointed.

When I execute code

```
Company::with(['users', 'machines'])->get()
```

`mysql.log` looks this way

```
select * from `company` where `company`.`id` = '48' limit 1
select * from `user` where `user`.`company_id` in ('48')
select * from `machine` where `machine`.`company_id` in ('48')
```

Why Laravel does not use joins for eager fetching? Also, are there any ways of improving perfomance and still using Laravel Models?

I know that Doctrine ORM eager loading works pretty nice by using joins.

---

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just a note, you don't need multiple `->with()` clauses, just use array syntax: `->with(["users", "machines"])` and `dot.notation` for chaining: `->with(["users", "users.other"])`, etc.

Comment: @TimLewis thank you, fixed.

Comment: No problem :) I don't think it affects performance in any way whatsoever, but it makes the code a little nicer to read/maintain. Also, good question; I've never really stopped to check the log like that, and I have an idea *why* it's done this way, but no idea if this is the most optimized or not.

Comment: @TimLewis if you feel your idea worth sharing, then share it with our community, please :)

Comment: Well, it's not really an answer, but I guess I can give some insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use joins instead of the Eloquent computed queries, I suppose you could just use the fluent query builder (that comes shipped with Laravel through the DB facade) and stick that code into a method of your model to keep everything nice and SRP.

For instance:

```
class Company extends Model {
    public function sqlWithJoin() {
        $users = DB::table('company')
        ->leftJoin('user', 'company.id', '=', 'user.company_id')
        ->get();

        return $users;
    }
}
```

This would generate a proper join query for you.

As for why you would want to do this, you would have to benchmark both options to see which one gives you the best performance for your specific data. I wouldn't generalize that one option always has better/worse performance than the other.

Comment: It's also worth keeping in mind that as you perform joins over more and more data the potential for locking tables gets larger - and this can degrade performance for other users on the site. Performing multiple select queries over each table is how most ActiveRecord implementations work.

Comment: @Dwight thank you for such an important clarification. Now I have a start point for investigation.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, I'm not sure performance-wise why this is the preferred method, but from usability, being able to access a model's relationships as it's own separate property is much easier than working with a `join`, especially in the event of a `many-to-one` relationship.

Let's compare the above example using both `->with()` and `->leftJoin()` methods.

When using `->with()` every relationship is defined as a property of `Company`, accessed via `$company->users`. It's easy to run a `foreach()` loop over this property `foreach($company->users AS $user)` and output information, such as `username`, `email`, etc. Also, if the `Company` has no `users`, you don't have to worry about displaying empty values (especially important on chaining models using `.` notation, such as `users.user_details`).

Now, looking at `leftJoin()`. If you try to chain multiple `leftJoins()` on each model and their sub-models, there's a chance you won't get the results you're expecting. Essentially, `leftJoin()` doesn't handle `NULL` records as well as individual queries can.

Next, to output a list of a company's users, you would have to run a loop such as:

```
foreach($company AS $row){
    echo $row->username;
    echo $row->email;
    // etc etc
}
```

This becomes problematic as `Eloquent` doesn't handle duplicate properties well at all. For example, if the company has an `email` field as well as the user, it's anyone's guess which is actually displayed. Unless you do a `selectRaw("companies.email AS email, users.email AS user_email)"`, only one `email` property is going to be returned. This also applies to columns like `id`, where multiple are going to be fetched by using `leftJoin()`, but only one will actually be accessible.

Long story short, `leftJoin()` comes with the potential for a lot of issues when trying to join multiple tables with the possibility of duplicate information, null information, etc. While the performance of running multiple queries using the `->with()` method may not be the best, it allows for easier use in retrieving and displaying information.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! Worth mention, that you can write `->select('companies.email as company_email')` on your query builder if you want to access both `user.email` and `companies.email`. I believe that there is some other reasons for Laravel to implement QB in such a way, because using joins stil allows us to do same things as by using queries. Take a look on Docrine ORM - it uses joins and still much more powerfull than Eloquent ORM.